# Is safety certification required for an electronic board that interfaces to LED driver?

Tags: led, safety, certification

LED drivers come with safety certification. If a company wants to build an electronic board to control the LED driver (say, on and off), does it need to be safety certified as well?

Comment: It depends on the end product, the application and where in the world it is used. For medical applications probably yes. For development purposes no. For anything else it back to 'it depends' just because this is a very broad subject. If you have a specific application ,input supply and the output values in voltage and current then you can get a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

no , if using a low voltage isolated enable or PWM input.

yes, if interfacing to the AC grid.

Comment: Depending on what markets you are selling it into, of course. If it has to be, say, explosive atmosphere rated for an application, well it would have to be certified to meet that...